# How to auto-run batch file as specific user (not scheduled task, not a duplicate)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, permissions, scripting, batch-file

I am an enterprise admin (Sr. Network Engineer), but my team does not manage Active Directory, so I am a little unfamiliar with policies and what is required to do what I am trying to achieve, and even the AD admins are failing me when it comes to my predicament.

I have a command that I am trying to turn into a script that is giving me some really weird behavior, and I need help sorting it out.

**First things first:**

- From my local workstation, I can open a command window by Shift-clicking and running as my domain admin user, and the command works just fine.
- From my local workstation, if I put this command in a script, and Shift-click to run the script as my domain admin user, the script/command works fine (as long as I give my domain admin account permissions).
- On the target machine where I want this script to run, I have confirmed that another domain admin can successfully execute the command.
- *If I launch a command prompt on this target machine when logged in with my domain admin account, the command fails (and also as a script).*

**Before you suggest something I've already tried or will not benefit me:**

- `runas` is not an option, because this script should not be interactive and prompted for a password.
- The `/savecred` parameter for `run as` is not an option because of password/security/audit policies.

**I have achieved the basic functionality, but it's messy:**

The basic command is something like this:

```
\\server\share\unlock.exe . username
```

The only way I can successfully execute this command without any Shift-clicking or `runas` nonsense is by putting this command in `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\unlock.bat` and then from my local machine creating a separate batch file that includes the following:

```
psexec \\targetmachine -u domainadmin -p domainpassword "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\unlock.bat"
```

**Questions and possible theories:**

- If I double-click this batch file on the target machine, should it not run as the username of the domain admin account that I'm logged into?
- Is it possible that since my domain admin is an admin on the target machine that when I run this command, it is trying to run as local Administrator?
- Every time I open a command prompt on this machine, it's automatically an Administrative prompt.  Is it possible that what I need is an un-elevated prompt, and if so, how do I get one when it automatically launches an Administrator prompt?

**Other details**:

- This is a terminal server running Windows 2008 R2 with a few different users accessing it, so I don't want to modify the behavior of how cmd.exe launches every time or anything.
- I realize I could specify a user if I run this as a scheduled task, but right now, I just want to run it from this server as a standalone script or command without any Shift-clicking.

**My main goal is to be able to logon to this server and simply double-click the batch file (and also be able to execute from a command prompt), while logged in as my domain admin account, which should be able to do this.**

Comment: @PJMahoney - it is the same domain admin account that I am using to run cmd.exe as a different user on my local machine as the one that I am logging in with on the TS.  I have all necessary permissions to this location. I also tried to state earlier that my domain admin acount *IS* a local admin on the TS. Also, I *DID* confirm visually that the other admin got this to work on this specific server.  There is no UAC prompt or DEP, that is not the issue.

Comment: @PJMahoney - also, the issue with typing the password is that I want to be able to distribute this batch file to other domain admins on this TS without having to modify it so that they can run it as-is when logged into their domain admin accounts and have it execute as-intended.  I just don't understand why I can't doubleclick the file and have it work. I have also visually confirmed in AD Users and Groups that the command/script actually works in the scenarios that I listed. If I can PsExec to the box and run the script, then I should be able to logon to the box and run it, plain and simple.

Comment: @PJMahoney - Correct, from my local Windows 10 machine that is joined to the domain, I am logged in with a local account.  I can Shift-click cmd.exe and run as my domain admin account, where this command works with no issues whatsoever. By "domain admin" I do mean, as you said, a member of the AD admin security group. When I run from my local machine as a different user, the domain admin account is the one I am referring to.

Comment: @PJMahoney - I will try to post an error message later tonight or possibly later this weekend. I just got off of a brutal on-call week, and don't have any intentions of firing up the VPN at the moment, but I can tell that the program DOES execute, it just does not unlock the user or display the status of the user. The specific error is an `LDAP_bind` error (or something of that sort). The other domain admin had me check the `%LOGONSERVER%` environment variable, and even when I set it the same as his, the program failed to unlock or show the status of the user, at which point he gave up.

Comment: @PJMahoney - That is exactly the unlock.exe that I am referring to, and I have seen it firsthand work flawlessly with Windows 2008 R2. Some of our admins use it all the time on that OS, and like I said, I witnessed a guy Shift-click > Run as his domain admin account, and it worked, and also, like I said, I can PsExec to this remote Windows 2008 R2 box from my local Windows 10 box and execute the batch file located on the 2008 R2 box just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**I knew all of this was too weird to be true.**

- I just now logged in as normal to the Terminal Server using my domain admin account.
- I double-clicked the script
- It worked flawlessly.

This does not answer the question of the troubles I was having yesterday and the issues that I was seeing, however, I have accomplished my main goal of double-clicking the script normally and having it execute as-expected with the intended results.

I made no changes, whatsoever, between yesterday and today.

My guess is that it was *"just one of those things..."*

Comment: my suggestion is that you need a service account that is a special way to run commands anywhere and keep the password protected. maybe an option. Remember to accept an answer if it solved already